# Re-install grafic driver for Lenovo Notebook

Tags: drivers, graphics, lenovo

The problem is, that i could only start Ubuntu at my notebook with the recovery mode. The system does not install the required grafic driver. Is there someone who can give advice how to find and install the required grafic driver?

Comment: additional info:

Comment: version: 15.04; i also tried to find out about the driver by use of 'lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2' the result tells me VGA compatible controller [0300]:  Intel Corporation Atom Prozessor Z36xx/Z37xx series graphics + display [8086:0f31] (rev 0e) Subsystem Lenovo Device [17aa:3905] and also: SATA Controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0f23] (rev 0e)

Comment: But i have no idea at all how to make use of this